# Is this layout achievable with flexbox and no media queries?

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I am carrying out my first "web design project?", and I am having this issue:

If the screen is +922px, I want the articles (flex-items) to fill as much width as available, but always forming a two-column layout inside the main (flex-container). When the screen is less than 922px, I want them to position in one column.

Is it possible to do this with flexbox, or I made a bad decision and I should use grid/media queries/column-count: 2 instead?

For now, I am uncapable to give the articles a reasonable width without them displaying into a 1-column layout when I shrink the page a little. I would like the items to shrink/grow a bit according to the browser length.

Sorry for my English by the way.

```
.main {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
    .main__title {
        min-width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .article {
        width: 500px;
    }

        .article__title {
            width: 100%;
        }

         .article__p {
            max-width: 75%;
            margin: 0px;
        } 
    
        .article__img {
            margin: 1em;
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
```

The entire code here: https://github.com/llfontbote/DAW-M9

Comment: What is wrong with using media queries? They are a fundamental part of flexbox and CSS-Grid.

Comment: Ok, I'm using media queries and flex-item { width: 46%.} then.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your HTML and CSS in a runnable snippet that the community could use to help with your issue?